# Filing an extension on taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes

I need to file an extension on my taxes.  My program is asking me to estimate taxes due/balance owed.  However, I will have a refund (the IRS owes me money), say of X dollars.

So should I write that I estimate that I owe $0 or should I write that I estimate that I owe $-X?

Comment: If you will receive a refund why would you need to file an extension?

Comment: I assumed this was required.

Comment: From TurboTax - "If you are getting a refund. ... If you have a refund coming from the IRS—as about three out of four taxpayers do every year—then there is no penalty for failing to file your tax return by the deadline, even if you don't ask for an extension."